# Instagram API /media/search maximum count parameter?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

When using Python to make a GET request to the Instagram API, passing the required variables as shown below

```
photos = api.media_search(lat=latitude, lng=longitude, distance=distance, count=count)
```

I have attempted to set the count parameter to over 100, but the API returns a maximum of 100 results.

Is this a limitation set for the API or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `Instagram API` documentation says there is a max value for `count` for each endpoint, from the [`docs`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/):

> On views where pagination is present, we also support the `"count"` parameter. Simply set this to the number of items you'd like to receive. Note that the default values should be fine for most applications - but if you decide to increase this number **there is a maximum value defined on each endpoint**.

However, I couldn't find any indication for that number in the documentation, neither for the [`media`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) request nor for other requests. So I would assume that they don't guarantee any specific number.

They do specify that if the application is in [`sandbox mode`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/), the data is restricted to 20 most recent media.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the small print in the Instagram API documentation!

I've spent a day researching this issue, and it seems that the maximum value for the count parameter seems to be 100.

I've also attempted to work around the problem by retrieving the created_time attribute for every 100th photograph and passing that as max_timestamp for the next request, but so far I've been unsuccessful in implementing this.

Any ideas would be most welcome!

Comment: This is a bit of an old question but I'm running into the same issue, what you can do is instead of sending the `created_time` as `max_timestamp` you can get the `id` of the last post you got and send that in the next request as `max_id`. That way you will get the 100 posts that were created earlier than the last one you got in the first request