# correct link Instagram API?

Tags: java, android, instagram

Why i get the same result, if i call this link:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&distance=20

(result for this):

```
{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": [{"latitude": 48.858386309412, "id": "2593354", "longitude": 2.2945538162266, "name": "Tour Eiffel"}, {"latitude": 48.858447741866, "id": "263928560", "longitude": 2.2939224301988, "name": "Paris Effiel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.8567, "id": "6889842", "longitude": 2.3508, "name": "Paris, France"}, {"latitude": 48.858386309412, "id": "264033675", "longitude": 2.2945538162266, "name": "On The Top Of The Eiffel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.858222222222, "id": "303190233", "longitude": 2.2945, "name": "Altitude 95"}, {"latitude": 48.859031848881, "id": "257881339", "longitude": 2.2935777831503, "name": "Restaurant 58 At The Eiffel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.858257700528, "id": "276056134", "longitude": 2.2944542005724, "name": "Eiffel Tower Sommett, Paris, France"}, {"latitude": 48.85478, "id": "253202376", "longitude": 2.30038, "name": "La Tour Effiel"}, {"latitude": 48.858496, "id": "215715721", "longitude": 2.294364, "name": "Restaurant Jules Verne on top of the Eiffel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.858653598246, "id": "213790743", "longitude": 2.2940427451409, "name": "58 Tour Eiffel (officiel)"}, {"latitude": 48.8578199, "id": "255844661", "longitude": 2.29517, "name": "Torre Eiffel Paris"}, {"latitude": 48.85478, "id": "249042610", "longitude": 2.30038, "name": "Eiffle Tower, Paris"}, {"latitude": 48.858318956201, "id": "235257238", "longitude": 2.2944272576363, "name": "Le Jules Verne - Tour Eiffel"}, {"latitude": 48.862744073789, "id": "213735539", "longitude": 2.2877834063019, "name": "Trocadero - Eiffel Tower - Paris"}, {"latitude": 48.8587977826, "id": "501461117", "longitude": 2.29279927942, "name": "Pont Alexandre lll, Paris"}, {"latitude": 48.858343014454, "id": "480084479", "longitude": 2.2944097434573, "name": "58 Tour Eiffel Restaurant Eiffel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.858694031165, "id": "266272154", "longitude": 2.2942663101873, "name": "56 Eiffel Tower Restaurant"}, {"latitude": 48.855300021947, "id": "253194889", "longitude": 2.292627008778, "name": "Louvre Museum"}, {"latitude": 48.845153069693, "id": "220099992", "longitude": 2.2911305275305, "name": "Paris 15E"}, {"latitude": 48.8582503385, "id": "244607485", "longitude": 2.30800565868, "name": "Rio Sena - Paris"}]}
```

and this:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&distance=600

(and the result of the second one):

```
{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": [{"latitude": 48.858386309412, "id": "2593354", "longitude": 2.2945538162266, "name": "Tour Eiffel"}, {"latitude": 48.858447741866, "id": "263928560", "longitude": 2.2939224301988, "name": "Paris Effiel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.8567, "id": "6889842", "longitude": 2.3508, "name": "Paris, France"}, {"latitude": 48.858386309412, "id": "264033675", "longitude": 2.2945538162266, "name": "On The Top Of The Eiffel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.858222222222, "id": "303190233", "longitude": 2.2945, "name": "Altitude 95"}, {"latitude": 48.859031848881, "id": "257881339", "longitude": 2.2935777831503, "name": "Restaurant 58 At The Eiffel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.858257700528, "id": "276056134", "longitude": 2.2944542005724, "name": "Eiffel Tower Sommett, Paris, France"}, {"latitude": 48.85478, "id": "253202376", "longitude": 2.30038, "name": "La Tour Effiel"}, {"latitude": 48.858496, "id": "215715721", "longitude": 2.294364, "name": "Restaurant Jules Verne on top of the Eiffel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.858653598246, "id": "213790743", "longitude": 2.2940427451409, "name": "58 Tour Eiffel (officiel)"}, {"latitude": 48.8578199, "id": "255844661", "longitude": 2.29517, "name": "Torre Eiffel Paris"}, {"latitude": 48.85478, "id": "249042610", "longitude": 2.30038, "name": "Eiffle Tower, Paris"}, {"latitude": 48.858318956201, "id": "235257238", "longitude": 2.2944272576363, "name": "Le Jules Verne - Tour Eiffel"}, {"latitude": 48.862744073789, "id": "213735539", "longitude": 2.2877834063019, "name": "Trocadero - Eiffel Tower - Paris"}, {"latitude": 48.8587977826, "id": "501461117", "longitude": 2.29279927942, "name": "Pont Alexandre lll, Paris"}, {"latitude": 48.858343014454, "id": "480084479", "longitude": 2.2944097434573, "name": "58 Tour Eiffel Restaurant Eiffel Tower"}, {"latitude": 48.858694031165, "id": "266272154", "longitude": 2.2942663101873, "name": "56 Eiffel Tower Restaurant"}, {"latitude": 48.855300021947, "id": "253194889", "longitude": 2.292627008778, "name": "Louvre Museum"}, {"latitude": 48.845153069693, "id": "220099992", "longitude": 2.2911305275305, "name": "Paris 15E"}, {"latitude": 48.8582503385, "id": "244607485", "longitude": 2.30800565868, "name": "Rio Sena - Paris"}]}
```

It's simply the same.

Is the syntax of the link correct?
The parameter 'distance' doesn't change the range of the result?

Comment: Assuming you are not getting the error message (i.e. - you don't call that link exactly, but rather substituting your access token for "ACCESS-TOKEN" in the URLs), are you sure there are locations in the 600m radius circle around your centre point that are not within 20m from it? Try using a centre point and distances you KNOW have at least one location that should be in the second response but not in the first one.

It would also help if you added here the responses you get.

Comment: yes i'm sure. i tested it on many location points. i get always the same range.

Comment: @et_l there are location listed, that are some miles away.

Comment: if they are some miles away then they are not within 600m (I'm pretty sure that 'm' stands for 'metres' and not 'miles', as the default is 50 and default of 500 miles would be quite absurd in my opinion. Also, metres are usually shorthanded into 'm').     
Can you please add the results you get for the two queries into the question?

Comment: *the default is 500 - sorry for the typo

Comment: @et_l i updated my question. and yes 'm' stands for meters, but this isn't even better because there are locations listed more than 750m (the max) away. For example the distance of 'tour eiffel' to 'paris, france' is about  4-5km. Apart from this, i think the same result with different distances can't be correct...

Comment: Using [this tool](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) it looks like their distance is just over 40 metres, but that still means they should not appear together in a result to a query that asks for distance=20 (first one). The same site also calculated above 50 metres distance between the centre point and the first location in the result - so you are right that there is a problem here.  To me it looks like a bug, but I don't use the instagram api so I'll leave it for other people to try and help here.

Comment: By the way, the fact that the results are the same is less interesting, as they are both truncated results at 20 locations (there are more locations probably for both results, but the api gives you only the first 20 of them. You can add the `count` parameter to ask for more but this parameter is limited for 20 if your app is still in the sandbox mode - look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228087/instagram-api-media-search-maximum-count-parameter) regarding media search).

Comment: @et_l ok. thanks for that hint!